# How to set ScaleTransform ScaleX property value in xaml from xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am dynamically changing the canvas background in my app.

The `page.xaml` code is:

```
   <Canvas x:Name="canvasBoard" Height="695" Width="1365" Grid.Row="0">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="/Assets/board.png"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
```

I want to change the `ScaleTransfom ScaleX` value dynamically to the background selected by the `page.xaml.cs` but am unable to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the value of `ScaleX` from code which I think is what you are asking you can do that with the following code in `page.xaml.cs`:

```
(canvasBoard.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform).ScaleX = 10;
```